# Spring - return nested documents using aggregation

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework

i have 2 class

```
class Team
{
    @Id
    var lateint id : String

    var name : String? = null

    var stadium : String? = null

    var players : List<Players>? = null
}

class Player
{
    @Id
    var lateint id : String

    var firstName : String? = null

    var lastName : String? = null

    var post : PlayerPost? = null

    var number : Int? = null
}
```

i am trying to get a filtered list of player of a specific team, but i always get a wrong result.

this is my request

```
val teamCriteria = Criteria.where("_id").`is`(teamId)

val postCriteria = Criteria.where("post").`is`("DEFENDER")

val aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.match(teamCriteria),
    Aggregation.unwind("players"),
    Aggregation.match(postCriteria),
)

return mongoDb.aggregate(aggregation, Team::class.java, Player::class.java).mappedResults
```

The problem is instead of getting a list of players as result, i get the team duplicated as the number of expected players..

expected result

```
[
    {
        "id" : "id1",
        "firstName" : "player1"
        "lastName" : "player1",
        "number" : 2,
        "post" : "DEFENDER"
    },
    {
        "id" : "id2",
        "firstName" : "player2"
        "lastName" : "player2",
        "number" : 3,
        "post" : "DEFENDER"
    }
]
```

i always get this result

```
[
    {
        "id" : "id1",
        "name" : "team name"
        "stadium" : "stadium name",
        "players" : []
    },
    {
        "id" : "id1",
        "name" : "team name"
        "stadium" : "stadium name",
        "players" : []
    }
]
```

Can sameone tell me what's wrong in my code?

Comment: if you need players from a single team only, you can keep it really simple. You could just query the team by `id` and filter the payers by `post` in your code. Aggregation would be more of use if you want players from different teams with a certain `post`

Comment: @harsh i know, but i m trying to use this solution because i started to learn aggregation and i want to familiarize myself with this framework